# How to asynchronously update state using useState before calling a function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, async-await

I'm working on a React application, and I have a situation where I need to update a state variable using `useState` and then call a function that depends on the updated state. Specifically, I'm looking for a solution where the state update happens asynchronously, and I want to ensure that the state is updated before the function call.

As an example, let's consider a common use case where I have a login button. When the button is pressed, I need to first update the `email` and `password` states and then call a `handleLogin` function that uses these credentials for authentication.

I've tried using `async/await` with the state update functions, but it doesn't seem to guarantee that the state updates are completed before the function call.

Here's what I've attempted:

```
const handleLoginButtonPress = async () => {
  await setEmail(userInfo.email);
  await setPassword(userInfo.password);
  handleLogin();
};
// ...
<button onClick={handleLoginButtonPress}>Login</button>
```

This approach doesn't seem to work reliably.

In this case, I want to load the credentials from local storage (though it's not ideal), then call handleLogin (API call) on the button press event. However, I wanted to know, in general, how to update the state and then perform an action in a single event.

Comment: use `setTimeout` to the handlelogin function

Comment: Why not `handleLogin(userInfo)`?

Comment: @ray This is for autofill type login for existing account.

Comment: It's not clear from your question why you need the email and password to be in the  component state at all.

Comment: I think you might need a useEffect block which has email and password in it's dependency array. Inside oyu need to check if they are set and just in that case call handleLogin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React state updates don't take effect until the next render. You can set up a `useEffect` hook to conditionally call your `handleLogin` function after setting email and password.

You could pull this off with a ref instead of state for the `doLogin` condition, but here's a proof-of-concept implementation. When you click the button, email and password state get set, and on the next render you can see via the console that the new state is available for the handleLogin call.

```js
function App () {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
  const [doLogin, setDoLogin] = React.useState(false);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (doLogin) {
      console.log(`do login with "${email}", "${password}"`);
      setDoLogin(false);
    }
  }, [doLogin])
  
  const doLoginStuff = () => {
    setEmail('me@example.com');
    setPassword('correct horse battery staple');
    setDoLogin(true);
  }
  
  return (
      <button onClick={doLoginStuff}>Do Login Stuff</button>
  )
}

const domNode = document.getElementById('app');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domNode);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```